# rails 3, new model B is 1:1 with old model A, how to auto create new B record for each already-existing A record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, model-associations

Rails v3.0.3
Original schema has **customers** table, and the app has data for 100 customers.

via migration we add **cust_info** table with 1:1, eg:

```
customers has_one cust_info 
cust_info belongs_to customers
```

so right now (after running `rake db:migrate` to create the new model) we have 100 'old' **customer** records that do not have the 1:1 required **cust_info** record.

QUES (1a) (legacy data update) what is the "rails way" to generate the required (empty) **cust_info** record for each of our 100 existing **customer** records?

QUES (2) (going forward) how to we modify our app so when we create a NEW **customer** record it will automatically create an associated **cust_info** record at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Because you've a small dataset, I'd work in the console:

```
Customer.all.each do |c|
   c.create_cust_info.save
end
```

Q2: use the following callback: `after_create` in your customer model and build the cust_info inside